# how to import oracle 11g dump file to 10g oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-dump

when I tried to import oracle database 11g into oracle 10g I got this error.

> IMP:00010 Not a valid export file. header failed identification
>
> IMP:00000 Import terminated unsucessfully

any help, please

Comment: You should take the export using 10g export utility and then import in 10g using 10g import utility. That ways it will work.

Answer (score 6):

You can import your `Oracle 11g` `expdp dump file` into `Oracle 10g` if you make sure you use `VERSION=10.2` parameter during export. like:

---

```
expdp hr/hr TABLES=hr.employees VERSION=10.2 DIRECTORY=data_pump_dir 
DUMPFILE=emp.dmp LOGFILE=emp.log
```

*(Assuming you want to import in `Oracle 10.2`)*

and use `impdp` as usual, like:

```
impdp hr/hr TABLES=hr.employees DIRECTORY=data_pump_dir
DUMPFILE=emp.dmp LOGFILE=emp_imp.log
```

Comment: i want to import the entire schemas separately

Comment: @ezzaam - for full information Click: [expdp impdp](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php) and find `Schema Exports/Imports` and `Database Exports/Imports`

Comment: or just provide what you have tried... so i can give you your desired input.

Answer (score 4):

From oracle KB:

```
IMP-00010: Not a valid export file, header failed verification

Cause: Either it is not a file generated by the Export utility or that the file is corrupted. 

Action: Check if file was transferred in Binary-mode. If the file was indeed generated by the Export utility, **and no compatibility issue is related**, report this as an Import bug.
```

As Incognito says you:
If you want to move data from a higher version database to a lower version database using exp/imp utilities, you must run the exp client version matching the target database against the source database.

The followings are the compatibility matrix for exp/imp utilities between different versions

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|  EXPORT   |                       IMPORT into:                           | 
|   from    +--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------------+ 
|    \/     |  8.1.7 |  9.2.0 | 10.1.0 | 10.2.0 | 11.1.0 | 11.2.0 |        | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
|  5.x  1)2)| EXP5x  | EXP5x  | EXP5x  | EXP5x  | EXP5x  | EXP5x  |        | 
|  6.x    2)| EXP6x  | EXP6x  | EXP6x  | EXP6x  | EXP6x  | EXP6x  |        | 
|  7.x    3)| EXP7x  | EXP7x  | EXP7x  | EXP7x  | EXP7x  | EXP7x  |        | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
|  8.0.3    | EXP803 | EXP803 | EXP803 | EXP803 | EXP803 | EXP803 |        | 
|  8.0.4    | EXP804 | EXP804 | EXP804 | EXP804 | EXP804 | EXP804 |        | 
|  8.0.5    | EXP805 | EXP805 | EXP805 | EXP805 | EXP805 | EXP805 |        | 
|  8.0.6    | EXP806 | EXP806 | EXP806 | EXP806 | EXP806 | EXP806 |        | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
|  8.1.5    | EXP815 | EXP815 | EXP815 | EXP815 | EXP815 | EXP815 |        | 
|  8.1.6    | EXP816 | EXP816 | EXP816 | EXP816 | EXP816 | EXP816 |        | 
|  8.1.7    | EXP817 | EXP817 | EXP817 | EXP817 | EXP817 | EXP817 |        | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
|  9.0.1    | EXP817 | EXP901 | EXP901 | EXP901 | EXP901 | EXP901 |        | 
|  9.2.0    | EXP817 | EXP920 | EXP920 | EXP920 | EXP920 | EXP920 |        | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
| 10.1.0  4)| EXP817 | EXP920 |                 4)                |        | 
| 10.2.0  4)|   N/S  | EXP920 |                 4)                |        | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
| 11.1.0  4)|   N/S  | EXP920*|        4)       |        5)       |        | 
| 11.2.0  4)|   N/S  | EXP920*|        4)       |        5)       |        | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+




+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|  EXPORT   |                       IMPORT into:                           | 
|   from    +--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
|    \/     |   5.x  |   6.x  |   7.x  |  7.3.x |  8.0.x |  8.1.x |  9.0.1 | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
|  5.x 1) 2)| EXP5x  | EXP5x  | EXP5x  | EXP5x  | EXP5x  | EXP5x  | EXP5x  | 
|  6.x    2)|  N/S   | EXP6x  | EXP6x  | EXP6x  | EXP6x  | EXP6x  | EXP6x  | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
|  7.0.x  3)|  N/S   | EXP6x  | EXP7x  | EXP70x | EXP70x | EXP70x | EXP70x | 
|  7.1.x  3)|  N/S   | EXP6x  | EXP7x  | EXP71x | EXP71x | EXP71x | EXP71x | 
|  7.2.x  3)|  N/S   | EXP6x  | EXP7x  | EXP72x | EXP72x | EXP72x | EXP72x | 
|  7.3.x  3)|  N/S   | EXP6x  | EXP7x  | EXP73x | EXP72x | EXP73x | EXP73x | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
|  8.0.x  4)|  Not Supported  | EXP7x  | EXP73x | EXP80x | EXP80x | EXP80x | 
|  8.1.x  4)|  Not Supported  | EXP7x  | EXP73x | EXP80x | EXP81x | EXP81x | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
|  9.0.1.x  |           Not Supported           |    5)  | EXP81x | EXP901 | 
|  9.2.0.x  |           Not Supported           |    5)  |   N/S  | EXP901 | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
| 10.1.0.x  |                    Not Supported                    | EXP901 | 
| 10.2.0.x  |                    Not Supported                    |   N/S  | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
| 11.1.0.x  |                         Not Supported                        | 
| 11.2.0.x  |                         Not Supported                        |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Regards
Giova

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this (not coolest one, but handy) is that open the DMP from 11G with vi or any kind of good text/console editor and in the first lines of the file.

It shows the version number 11 (in this case), so you can just edit the text and change it then save it. After this you can try to load the DMP and will work.

This is the Punk way!

Hope it helps and pardon my broken english

Answer (score 0):

IMP-00010: not a valid export file, header failed verification
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully

because dump from linux but you import from window. 
action: imp from linux